# HornetQ Clustering Specific Queue and Topic

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I was using HorentQ in clustered mode in JBoss AS 7.1; However I wanted to see if I can cluster specific topics and queues only. I understood from [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/clusters.html) that it is possible by configuring the address. However I am not able to find the address which works. Here is a snapshot of the doamin.xml; Where clustering is NOT working

```
              <cluster-connections>
                    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                        <address>mro</address>
                        <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                    </cluster-connection>
                </cluster-connections>
```

Here is how the Queue and topic is defined. Changing the address to *jms* makes everything clustered and it is working, but that is not what I want

```
                 <jms-queue name="MROQueue">
                        <entry name="mro/MROQueue"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/mro/MROQueue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                   <jms-topic name="MROTopic">
                        <entry name="mro/MROTopic"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/mro/MROTopic"/>
                    </jms-topic>
```

Comment: Got more info but still not able https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/HornetQ_User_Guide/wildcard-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried various wildcards in the address but nothing was working. So in the end got this working

```
 <cluster-connections>
                    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                        <address>jms.queue.cluster</address>
                        <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                    </cluster-connection>
                </cluster-connections>
```

and queues

```
<jms-queue name="cluster.MROQueue">
                        <entry name="cluster.MROQueue"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/cluster.MROQueue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
  <jms-topic name="cluster.MROTopic">
                        <entry name="cluster.MROTopic"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/cluster.MROTopic"/>
                    </jms-topic>
```

The above made both my Queues and Topics to be clustered. To test I changed to

```
 <cluster-connections>
                    <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                        <address>jms.queue.cluster3</address>
                        <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                    </cluster-connection>
                </cluster-connections>
```

And changed queues to

```
 <jms-queue name="cluster2.MROQueue">
                        <entry name="cluster2.MROQueue"/>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/cluster2.MROQueue"/>
                    </jms-queue>
```

and it did not cluster; So that seems to be the way at least in this version for specific clustering

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:

> address. Each cluster connection only applies to messages sent to an address that starts with this value. **Note: this does not use wild-card matching.**

https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/clusters.html#clusters.cluster-connections

What is **not in the documentation** is how the address is formed, it does say

> All JMS queues and topic subscriptions are bound to addresses that
>   start with "jms."